# wicket : Unable to find component with id ... with table , listview and populateitem

Tags: wicket

Excuse me, i'm newest in wicket and i have an error that i can't fix. please help me !

here a consultation page:

```
<body>
    <wicket:extend>
        <div>
            <a href="#" wicket:id="idLinkHaut"><img wicket:id="imgRetourHaut" /><span>
                    Retour</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="marginTop">
            <span wicket:id="panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal" />
        </div>
        <div class="marginTop">
            <a href="#" wicket:id="idLinkBas"><img wicket:id="imgRetourBas" /><span>Retour</span></a>
        </div>
    </wicket:extend>
</body>
```

the  java page : consultation.java

```
public class ConsultationPage extends HeaderTemplatePage {

    @SpringBean(name = "dao")
    private GetDiagnosticDao dao;

    /**
     * Constructeur de la page de consultation
     *
     * @param pp
     *            les paramètres de la page
     */
    public ConsultationPage(PageParameters pp) {
        super(pp);

        String idDiagnostic = ConstantesGlobales.PARAMETRE_ID_DIAGNOSTIC);
        // utile pour les liens RETOUR
        String singleResult =ConstantesGlobales.PARAMETRE_SINGLE_RESULT;
        // ndClient saisi dans le formulaire
        String numeroClient = ConstantesGlobales.PARAMETRE_ND_CLIENT_DEMANDE;
        // nunmerolient saisi dans le formulaire
        String typeDiag = ConstantesGlobales.PARAMETRE_TYPE_DIAGNOSTIC;


        Diagnostic diagnostic = null;
        String codeErreurException = StringUtils.EMPTY;
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(idDiagnostic)) {
            try {
                diagnostic = dao.getDiagnostic(idDiagnostic);

                numeroClient = getNdClient(nunmerolient, diagnostic);
                LOGGER.debug("DÃ©tail du diagnostic " + idDiagnostic + " pour le client " + numeroClient);
            } catch (FunctionalException | TechnicalException e) {
                codeErreurException = e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        // HomePage
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(codeErreurException)) {
            PageParameters consultationPageParameters = new PageParameters();
            consultationPageParameters.set(ConstantesGlobales.PARAMETRE_CODE_ERREUR, codeErreurException);
            consultationPageParameters.set(ConstantesGlobales.PARAMETRE_CLIENT, numeroClient);
            consultationPageParameters.set(ConstantesGlobales.PARAMETRE_TYPE_DIAGNOSTIC, typeDiag);
            throw new RestartResponseException(ListeDiagnosticsPage.class, consultationPageParameters);
        } else {
            // Titre de la page du navigateur
            add(new Label("titrePage", nunmerolient + " : diagnostic détaillé"));

            PageParameters pars = new PageParameters();
            if (WicketSession.get().isAppelPATH()) {
                pars.add(ConstantesGlobales.PARAMETRE_ORIGINE, ConstantesGlobales.VALEUR_ORIGINE_PATH);
            }
            if (!StringUtils.equals(ConstantesGlobales.VALEUR_SINGLE_RESULT, singleResult)) {
                // cas plusieurs diagnostics pour le numeroClient
                pars.add(ConstantesGlobales.PARAMETRE_CLIENT, numeroClient);
                pars.add(ConstantesGlobales.PARAMETRE_TYPE_DIAGNOSTIC, typeDiag);
            }

            ajouterLienHaut(pars);

            ajouterLienBas(pars);

            final ListeEquipementReseauLocal listeEquipements = new ListeEquipementReseauLocal("panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal", diagnostic);
            add(listeEquipements);

        }
    }

    /**
     * @param pars
     */
    private void ajouterLienBas(PageParameters pars) {
        final BookmarkablePageLink<ListeDiagnosticsPage> linkBas = new BookmarkablePageLink<>("idLinkBas",
                ListeDiagnosticsPage.class, pars);
        linkBas.add(new Image("imgRetourBas", new PackageResourceReference(LocateResources.class, GIF)));
        add(linkBas);
    }

    /**
     * @param pars
     */
    private void ajouterLienHaut(PageParameters pars) {
        final BookmarkablePageLink<ListeDiagnosticsPage> linkHaut = new BookmarkablePageLink<>("idLinkHaut",
                ListeDiagnosticsPage.class, pars);
        linkHaut.add(new Image("imgRetourHaut", new PackageResourceReference(LocateResources.class, GIF)));
        add(linkHaut);
    }

    /**
     * Cette mÃ©thode permet de rÃ©cupÃ©rer le numeroClient dans le cas mode
     * d'accÃšs depuis la fenÃªtre e-chat
     *
     * @param numeroClient
     * @param diagnostic
     * @return
     */
    private String getNunmerolient(String numeroClient, Diagnostic diagnostic) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(numeroClient) && diagnostic.getDiagnostic() != null) {
            final MonDiagnostic monDiagnostic = diagnostic.getDiagnostic();
            if (monDiagnostic.getInstalledOffer() != null && monDiagnostic.getInstalledOffer().getAliases() != null) {
                final Alias alias = monDiagnostic.getInstalledOffer().getAliases();
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(alias.getNd())) {
                    numeroClient = alias.getNd();
                }
            }
        }
        return numeroClient;
    }
}
```

the panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal has been built by:

listEquipementReseau.html

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/">

<wicket:panel>
    <div class="Block">
        <p class="titreTableau">Diagnostic des &eacute;quipements du r&eacute;seau local</p>
        <table class="tableauData" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="titreCentre">
                    <th>Nom de l'&eacute;quipement</th>
                    <th>Adresse MAC</th>
                    <th>Diagnostic</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="liste" wicket: id="listeEquipements">
                    <td><span wicket:id="idNomEquipement"></span></td> 
                    <td><span wicket:id="idMAC"></span></td>
                    <td><span wicket:id="idDiagnostic"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</wicket:panel>
</html>
```

And by ListeEquipementReseauLocal.java

```
public class ListeEquipementReseauLocal extends Panel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3844512423568512666L;
    private final String LBOX = "LB_MAC";
    public ListeEquipementReseauLocal(String id, Diagnostic diagnostic) {
        super(id);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub     
        if (diagnostic == null) {
            this.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            final List<EquipementReseauLocal> listeEquipements = getDataEquipements(diagnostic);

            final DataviewListeEquipementsReseauLocal dataView = new DataviewListeEquipementsReseauLocal("listeEquipements",
                    new ListDataProvider<EquipementReseauLocal>(listeEquipements));
            add(dataView);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Cette méthode permet de récupérer les données pour le bloc Tests Réalisés
     * 
     * @param diagnostic
     * @return
     */
    public List<EquipementReseauLocal> getDataEquipements(final Diagnostic diagnostic) {
        final List<EquipementReseauLocal> listeEquipements = new ArrayList<EquipementReseauLocal>();
        if (diagnostic.getDiagnostic() != null && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(diagnostic.getDiagnostic().getLanActions())) {
            for (Action action : diagnostic.getDiagnostic().getLanActions()) {
                final EquipementReseauLocal equipement = new EquipementReseauLocal();
                if (action.getServiceTest() != null) {
                    final ServiceTest serviceTest = action.getServiceTest();
                    if (serviceTest.getResultSummary() != null) {
                        final ResultSummary resultSummary = serviceTest.getResultSummary();
                        final List<ResultDetails> listResultDetails= serviceTest.getResultDetails();

                        // Code Diagnostic
                        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(resultSummary.getEvaluationCode())) {
                            equipement.setDiagnostic(resultSummary.getCodeDiagnostic());
                        }

                        for(ResultDetails rd : listResultDetails) {

                            // Libellé équipement
                            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(rd.getKey()) && !(rd.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("DATE"))) {
                                if(rd.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(LBOX))
                                    equipement.setNomEquipement("Livebox");
                                if(rd.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(LBOX))
                                    equipement.setNomEquipement("Galaxy-S8-1");
                                if(rd.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(LBOX))
                                    equipement.setNomEquipement("Mini-nous");
                                if(rd.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(LBOX))
                                    equipement.setNomEquipement("Decodeur TV");

                                // MAC
                                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(rd.getValue())) {
                                    equipement.setAdresseMac(rd.getValue());
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                listeEquipements.add(equipement);
            }
        }
        return listeEquipements;
    }
}
```

the table is filling by

DataviewListeEquipementsReseauLocal.java

```
public class DataviewListeEquipementsReseauLocal extends DataView<EquipementReseauLocal> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3176152958105694572L;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
            .getLogger(DataviewListeEquipementsReseauLocal.class);

    /**
     * Constructeur
     * 
     * @param id
     * @param dataProvider
     */
    public DataviewListeEquipementsReseauLocal(final String id,
            final IDataProvider<EquipementReseauLocal> dataProvider) {
        super(id, dataProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(Item<EquipementReseauLocal> item) {
        final EquipementReseauLocal equipement = item.getModelObject();

        String nomEquipement = ConstantesGlobales.NO_BREAK_SPACE;
        String adresseMAC = ConstantesGlobales.NO_BREAK_SPACE;
        String diagnostic = ConstantesGlobales.NO_BREAK_SPACE;

        if (equipement != null) {
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(equipement.getNomEquipement())) {
                nomEquipement = equipement.getNomEquipement();
            }
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(equipement.getAdresseMac())) {
                adresseMAC = equipement.getAdresseMac();
            }
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(equipement.getDiagnostic())) {
                diagnostic = equipement.getDiagnostic();
            }
        }

        item.add(new CustomLabel("idNomEquipement", nomEquipement));
        item.add(new CustomLabel("idMAC", adresseMAC));
        item.add(new CustomLabel("idDiagnostic", diagnostic));

    }


}
```

When i execute this code, this application, i have this error:

```
2018-12-06 09:13:15,062 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.wicket.MarkupContainer(1476) - Unable to find component with id 'idNomEquipement' in [ListeEquipementReseauLocal [Component id = panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal]]
    Expected: 'panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal.idNomEquipement'.
    Found with similar names: 'panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:1:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:2:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:3:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:4:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:5:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:6:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:7:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:8:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:9:idNomEquipement'
2018-12-06 09:13:15,069 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.w.DefaultExceptionMapper(114) - Unexpected error occurred
org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupException: Unable to find component with id 'idNomEquipement' in [ListeEquipementReseauLocal [Component id = panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal]]
    Expected: 'panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal.idNomEquipement'.
    Found with similar names: 'panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:1:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:2:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:3:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:4:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:5:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:6:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:7:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:8:idNomEquipement', panelDiagnosticEquipementsReseauxLocal:listeEquipements:9:idNomEquipement'
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupStream.throwMarkupException(MarkupStream.java:526) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1477) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1596) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1571) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:693) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.renderAssociatedMarkup(AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:76) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:112) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2556) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1534) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2386) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2314) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1432) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1596) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1571) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1525) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2556) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1534) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2386) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2314) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1432) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1596) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1571) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1525) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2556) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1534) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2386) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2314) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1432) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1596) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1571) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1525) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2556) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1534) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2386) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2314) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1432) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1596) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1571) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1525) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2556) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1534) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2386) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2314) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1432) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1596) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.onRender(Page.java:907) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.onRender(WebPage.java:140) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2386) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2314) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1035) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:105) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:224) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:167) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:784) ~[wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64) ~[wicket-request-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255) [wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212) [wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283) [wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:188) [wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:244) [wicket-core-1.5.7.jar:1.5.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.francetelecom.clara.security.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:273) [security-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.francetelecom.clara.security.filter.IpFilter.doFilter(IpFilter.java:70) [security-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

Comment: You always keep in mind in wicket you have to give same name in java as well as html.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling you have a Component with wicket:id=`idNomEquipe` in different part of your application.

The error says `ListeEquipes [Component id = panelDiagnosticEquipes]`, i.e. Wicket tries to find `idNomEquipe` in `panelDiagnosticEquipes`, not in `listeEquipes` (the ListView).

Comment: Hi, i founded the problem. The problem is the space  <tr class="liste" wicket: id="listeEquipements">. the space between wicket: and id.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is html you have given name as `idNomEquipes` in java you have the wicket id as `idNomEquipe` in the `listView` change the java name to `idNomEquipes` it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Compared to the previous question, I added additional courses so that the problem could be better understood. i am modifying my previous question

Answer (score 0):

i founded the problem. The problem is the space

```
<tr class="liste" wicket: id="listeEquipements">.
```

The space between wicket: and id. wicket doesn't understand the space between **wicket:** and **id**.